# cannot resolve method getAssets(); in a class when trying to play an mp3

Tags: java, android, class

I'm trying to access mp3 files from the assets folder and then setting the data source, preparing them and then playing them when an imagebutton is clicked. I keep getting an error on getAssets(), though. I know I need some context but I am not sure how to do it in my case. Every way that I have tried gives me some sort of error.

public class SoundFile {

```
public final MediaPlayer mp;
ImageButton position;



public SoundFile(Activity activity, int soundfile, int imgButtonId) {
    this.mp = new MediaPlayer();
    this.position = (ImageButton)activity.findViewById(imgButtonId);



    this.position.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        try{

            mp.reset();
            AssetFileDescriptor afd;
            afd = getAssets().openFd(mp);
            mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }});}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try This**
Replace

```
 afd = getAssets().openFd(mp);
```

with

```
afd =activity.getAssets().openFd(mp);
```